# How do I set onClickListener of a CheckBox in a clean way?

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener

I am trying to set an onClickListener of a CheckBox in Android.
I want the listener to execute two different methods depending on the checkbox status.
Is there a cleaner way to write the following Kotlin code?

```kotlin
private fun setExampleCbOnClickListener() {
    binding.exampleCb.setOnClickListener {
        when ((it as CheckBox).isChecked) {
            true -> methodOne()
            false -> methodTwo()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out in a clean way:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
   // TODO
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clickListener, you can use CheckChangeListener.
It will be triggered automatically when the checkbox state changes.

```
binding.exampleCb.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        when (isChecked) {
            true -> methodOne()
            false -> methodTwo()
        }
}
```